Book on Inflation models
I am wondering if there is a book (such as the Andersen Pieterbarg for rates) covering Inflation instead.
I need to study Inflation instruments, models, model calibration and instrument pricing.
I am especially interested in European and Italian inflation

Would the discussion of inflation in Brigo and Mercurio suffice for your purposes?

@DimitriVulis thanks for your advice. I'm going to look at it. Probably it could

The discussion of inflation in Brigo and Mercurio should suffice for most purposes.
Additional reading material that you may find useful: (If you can find online)

Jeroen Kerkhof (Lehman Research). Inflation Derivatives Explained:
Markets, Products, and Pricing (July 2005)

Arroub Zine-eddine (OpenGamma Quantitative Research). Inflation: Instruments and curve construction (January 2014)

Barclays. Inflation Derivatives: A User’s Guide (2005)

Barclays. Global Inflation-Linked Products: A User's Guide (2004)



The section on Inflation in Brigo Mercurio covers the following topics:
Pricing of Inflation-Indexed Derivatives

The Foreign-Currency Analogy
Definitions and Notation
The JY Model

Inflation-Indexed Swaps

Pricing of a ZCIIS
Pricing of a YYIIS
Pricing of a YYIIS with the JY Model
Pricing of a YYIIS with a First Market Model
Pricing of a YYIIS with a Second Market

Inflation-Indexed Caplets/Floorlets

Pricing with the JY Model
Pricing with the Second Market Model
Inflation-Indexed Caps

Calibration to market data
Introducing Stochastic Volatility

Modeling Forward CPI’s with Stochastic Volatility
Pricing Formulae

Exact Solution for the Uncorrelated Case
Approximated Dynamics for Non-zero Correlations


Example of Calibration

Pricing Hybrids with an Inflation Component

A Simple Hybrid Payoff

